# I'm trying to figure out my this node tree doesn't work. It's supposed revolve a curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

Before anyone suggests [Revolve/Screw Modifier Using Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269805/revolve-screw-modifier-using-geometry-nodes) I'm trying my own approach.

The idea that I would take a curve A that the user would draw and create a copy B by running it through a transform geometry node and scaling the down on the X and Y.

[image]

Then I would use a curve to mesh node to extrude a curve circle along B. I was hoping I could set the radius of each index B so that it matches A. The image below is what I was expecting.

[image: This is what it supposed to look like.]

However, what happens is that the radius is always 0 and I don't understand why especially because if I run it through a viewer node, it shows the values I was expecting. It's like they're not getting applied for some reason.

[image: Notice the viewer output]

Edit: Right after I posted this, I got it working.

[image]

Comment: Great! Would you please be so kind and could post this below as an answer so that this question can be closed? Thank you!

Comment: I've noticed there's an error in it. When the curve inverts like when you draw a U or n shape, all the geometry flips to the other side. Even though it's only mostly right, should I still post it as an answer?